# Ignoring .gitignore config/database.yml in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, configuration

When working on rails project (I'm still in the "beginner" phase of learning at the moment by the way) the file config/database.yml seems to be the one where things like database passwords etc. go. However, nobody seems to recommend putting it in the .gitignore file - why?

Surely I would need to exclude this or my sensitive database configuration details would end up being public knowledge if I pushed to github.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`database.yml` is the proper place for configuring your database credentials. Normally you'd commit `database.yml` while only configured with your development and testing environments.

I don't have passwords on my local Postgres and MySQL instances so I can safely commit `database.yml`. If you want to ignore it, just add `database.yml` line to the end of your `.gitignore` file. You'll need to make sure it's cleaned up and committed before ignoring it. Then you can make your changes safely.

Once you deploy to production you would symlink it in from a copy already stored on that server with the sensitive credentials.

Answer (score 4):

You should'nt have passwords in your database.yml....I don't. Why do you have passwords? If you deploy to heroku read: 
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

If you still want to ignore it add:

```
echo "database.yml" >> .gitignore
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the newbieness - the book i'm reading suggests that this is where they should go. If not in there, then where?

Comment: Well I don't have any passwords in my database.yml, I told you, I use env variables in deployment. If you have passwords in database.yml, then yes add it to the .gitignore.