# Why is config/database.yml included in the .gitignore file by default for my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, version-control

Why would config/database.yml be included in the .gitignore file by default?  This small item cost me an hour or two.

The way I stumbled into this trouble:

- I thought I was confused about how git handled reset and revert.
- I had been experimenting with code changes that affected config/database.yml
- I didn't like the result, so I abandoned the changes.
- It was odd, because it seemed I could not checkout an unedited version of  config/database.yml
- I then spent way too much time trying to figure out if I was misunderstanding git's reset and merge commands.
- Turns out config/database.yml was included in the .gitignore file by default.

Not sure why.  Cost me an hour or so of fiddling with reset and merge options, when it turns out I wasn't even tracking the file.  As I write this, I realize I am not entirely sure when .gitignore was written/modified to include config/database.yml

Is there some reason it should be there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file usually won't contain much interesting content for tracking in a version control system.

But, it **will** often contain passwords for connecting to a database server, which should not be made public.

It will also often contain information which needs to differ between different working copies, different user or database names for a database server, different paths to a SQLite file. These differences would make it impossible to track this file in the version control system.

Comment: a lot of deployment strategies will auto-generate database.yml, also.

Comment: Thanks qqx.  Very illuminating.  I waded into experimenting with connecting rails to multiple databases.  When I wanted to abandon the changes and go back to what I was doing, I was surprised that some seemingly important files were untracked.  Perhaps those who write rails tutorials for such things will note that this pitfall is out there.  Maybe some would consider my mistake a beginners error, but it cost me all the same.  In general, I have found no simple path to connect rails to multiple db's, but that's off-topic here.  Thanks again.

Comment: numbers, thanks.  Very helpful.  Deployment is a step I have yet to wrestle with.  Will keep your point in mind.

Comment: And I guees there is more here, now that I look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494783/ignoring-gitignore-config-database-yml-in-a-rails-project?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

If you are seeing a file for which 'git reset' and 'git revert' don't seem to have any effect, you may find the file is listed in the .gitignore file in your project root.

Comment: The question isn't 'is this file being ignored?', the question is 'WHY'.

Comment: sevenseacat,-1 ? There is more than one question/content point in the OP here.  -1 seems kinda' out of line.  And, those struggling with the problem contained in the stem of this question may be satisfied with this answer.  The follow-up answer adds understanding, but that doesn't mean this answer is worthy of a downvote.  Upvoting helps to identify best answers (which is below)  Downvoting should highlight nonconstructive answers, which this is not.